# Objective-C: JSON Unrecognised leading character?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ipad, nsmutablearray

when trying to execute little function to get an array using JSON i get the next message:

`-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x5d50e30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"`

This is the code

```
NSString * payloadAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData 
                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",payloadAsString);
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:
                                 [payloadAsString JSONValue]];
self.loginArray = jsonArray;
```

NSLog prints `[["True","1","MTY"]]` (as far as i know it should work).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of the json-framework you are using, but I modified the code to print the offending character:

In SBJSONParser.m:

```
- (BOOL)scanValue:(NSObject **)o
{
...
default:
[self addErrorWithCode:EPARSE description:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unrecognised leading character (%x)", c[-1]]];
//[self addErrorWithCode:EPARSE description: @"Unrecognised leading character"];
return NO;
}
```

You might try setting a breakpoint at that line of code instead.

Also, in general, you can try pasting the JSON into JSONLint at http://jsonlint.com/ to see if it validates. Your JSON does validate, though, so your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your string values are using a valid straight double quotation mark character.  I've seen people try to copy-paste JSON out of an editor only to have their quotes turned into open-quote close-quote pairs like these:

## “”

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and it turned out to be that the permissions on the directory used by the web service had been changed.